# Fourier Heat conduction law and two insulated layers heat conduction rate

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

If we apply Fourier heat conduction law to a system of two insulated layers joined together, of the same area, can we always assume that the rate of heat transfer between the layers will eventually reach the same value? If yes, then why?

Comment: If an oscillating temperature is applied to either side, the heat transfer between the layers will never converge to a constant value. I don't think this is what you're asking about. So more information is needed to clarify your question.

Comment: Do you expect heat to pile up somewhere without limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a **steady state condition**, when the internal energy of each layer keeps a constant value, the same amount of heat "crosses" the two layers.

**Remark.** This conclusion holds even without modelling heat conduction with Fourier's law.

Assuming no forces applied to these layers, a balance equation for the internal energy of each layer reads:

$$\frac{d E_i}{d t} = \sum_{k} \dot{Q}_{ik} \ ,$$

i.e. time derivative of the internal energy of each layer equals the overall flux of "incoming" heat, being $Q_{ij}$ the heat flux "from $j$ to $i$".

[image]

Given a setup where two layers, labelled as 1 and 2, separate two environments A and B, the balance for layer 1 and 2 reads

$$\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d E_1}{dt} & = \dot{Q}_{1A} + \dot{Q}_{12} \\
 \frac{d E_2}{dt} & = \dot{Q}_{21} + \dot{Q}_{2B} \ , \\
\end{aligned}$$

with $\dot{Q}_{12} = - \dot{Q}_{21}$. Thus, in a steady state condition, $\frac{d}{dt} \equiv 0$, and
$$ \dot{Q}_{1A} = \dot{Q}_{21} = \dot{Q}_{B2} \ .$$

Comment: So if we assume a steady state then we get the conclusion that you stated, I get that. But how can we assume that a steady state will always be reached?

Comment: It depends on your problem. You can't in general. If you add some more details, maybe in another question, we can study that system and evaluate if a steady condition may exist. If we're dealing with quite a simple conduction problem in solids, steady boundary conditions should be a sufficient condition to reach steady state.

Comment: I see. The question originates from a problem given as "Prove that for a compound layer of two different materials sandwiched together (such as air and glass, or brick and wood), the effective total R-value is the sum of the individual R values."                             Where R is thermal resistivity. If we assume a steady state then only the solution is possible, but I couldn't figure out why we can assume it.

Comment: Some assumptions in exercises are made to write exercises easier enough to be solved, without any other meaningful reasons. Now that you've clarified the question in your comment, let me have dinner, and I'll check if that statement about thermal resistivity holds even in non-stationary conditions

Comment: But if I remember right, thermal resistance is usually defined in stationary conditions, while for non-stationary conditions we need to solve the unsteady diffusion equation

Comment: I guess that the definition of thermal resistance has such a simple expression only in steady conditions

Comment: I see, thank you very much